# How do I open WebStorm from terminal?

Tags: webstorm, fish

I've looked around but I've only found answers for past versions. I have a new version of WebStorm and I want to open my projects from the command line, but `wstorm .` and `webstorm .` doesn't seem to work.

I've tried going to **Tools > Create Command Line Launcher...** and I get this:

[image: WebStorm image]

I go to ToolBox's WebStorm Settings and I'm met with this:

[image]

**Generate shell scripts** is turned on, but the but the commands still do not work in my terminal.

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to add in a Shell scripts location? I'm not entirely sure I understand.

Comment: This helped me, https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/enable-shell-scripts-for-the-jetbrains-toolbox-app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After opening a ticket with Jetbrains support, the default path is `/usr/local/bin`. Adding this worked.

[image: JetBrains Toolbox Shell Script]

Comment: Thank you, after extensive internet searching this comment came to the rescue.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 - similarly, this method does not work

Answer (score 20):

It's actually very easy. First you open up Webstorm, and press `SHIFT` twice. This will bring up a search box, where you type: `Create Command Line Launcher`. You will see a search result from `Tools` will be highlighted, click on it, and it will suggest the default path. Just click on `Ok`. Your command line launcher is now ready, so you can open terminal, `cd` to your project root folder, and type `webstorm ./` to launch webstorm.

If the `Create Command Line Launcher` option is not working, try the following:
If you are on MacOS, try adding the path as instructed in their [official page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html). And if you are on Linux, just uninstall the current version and reinstall as a snap package using `sudo snap install webstorm --classic`. This way, you can launch it from the terminal just by typing `webstorm`

Comment: I've done that too. I just get the first image in my question, that the Toolbox App settings is handling it. I don't know the default path.

Comment: In the `Shell scripts location` click select, it will give you a default path, then click ok without changing it.

Comment: @Dblaze47 it says not specified

Comment: @Andi I haven't tested the Webstorm versions lately, so will have to see how this is done on updated versions. At the time of the comment, I was using Ubuntu 18.04, so it might not work for Ubuntu 20 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [open-ide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-ide) tool. It allows you to define all of your editors and to open any folder with your editor straight from terminal